# 301 redirect via .htacess file to different domain

Tags: .htaccess, http, https, redirect

I need `.htaccess` code to 301 redirect `https://www.example.com` to `http://www.example.org`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In your .htacess file, type in the following:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.org/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

Source: [Setting up a permanent 301 redirect via .htacess - InMotion Hosting](http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/redirects/setting-up-a-301-permanent-redirect-via-htaccess)